# find duplicates in range SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have some sort of table containing lot of numeric data:
for instance, for one of the table I have such values

```
    CREATE TABLE `mdacardrange` (
  `rID` decimal(20,0) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 ,
  `range_begin` varchar(254) DEFAULT NULL,
  `range_end` varchar(254) DEFAULT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (`rID`),

);

INSERT INTO `mdacardrange` (`rID`,`range_begin`,`range_end`) VALUES (1,'4567890000000000000','4567899999999999000');
INSERT INTO `mdacardrange` (`rID`,`range_begin`,`range_end`) VALUES (2,'5264800000000000000','5264809999999999000');
INSERT INTO `mdacardrange` (`rID`,`range_begin`,`range_end`) VALUES (3,'5193060000000000000','5193069999999999000');
INSERT INTO `mdacardrange` (`rID`,`range_begin`,`range_end`) VALUES (4,'5482150000000000000','5482159999999999000');
INSERT INTO `mdacardrange` (`rID`,`range_begin`,`range_end`) VALUES (5,'5416710000000000000','5416719999999999000');
INSERT INTO `mdacardrange` (`rID`,`range_begin`,`range_end`) VALUES (6,'5167340000000000000','5167349999999999000');
INSERT INTO `mdacardrange` (`rID`,`range_begin`,`range_end`) VALUES (7,'4043090000000000000','4043099999999999000');
INSERT INTO `mdacardrange` (`rID`,`range_begin`,`range_end`) VALUES (8,'4043110000000000000','4043119999999999000');
INSERT INTO `mdacardrange` (`rID`,`range_begin`,`range_end`) VALUES (9,'4226060000000000000','4226069999999999000');
INSERT INTO `mdacardrange` (`rID`,`range_begin`,`range_end`) VALUES (10,'4043100000000000000','4043109999999999000');
INSERT INTO `mdacardrange` (`rID`,`range_begin`,`range_end`) VALUES (11,'4063710000000000000','4063719999999999000');
INSERT INTO `mdacardrange` (`rID`,`range_begin`,`range_end`) VALUES (12,'4098050000000000000','4098059999999999000');
INSERT INTO `mdacardrange` (`rID`,`range_begin`,`range_end`) VALUES (15,'4779040000000000000','4779049999999999999');
INSERT INTO `mdacardrange` (`rID`,`range_begin`,`range_end`) VALUES (16,'5223050000000000000','5223059999999999999');
INSERT INTO `mdacardrange` (`rID`,`range_begin`,`range_end`) VALUES (17,'4703770000000000000','4703779999999999000');
INSERT INTO `mdacardrange` (`rID`,`range_begin`,`range_end`) VALUES (18,'5483930000000000000','5483939999999999000');
INSERT INTO `mdacardrange` (`rID`,`range_begin`,`range_end`) VALUES (19,'5341480000000000000','5341489999999999999');
```

My task is to compare this data ranges for duplicates. Unfortunately, i don't even know how to deal with such data, as i understand, somehow i need to calculate whole ranges for each row, and then compare, can somebody help me with such issue?

Comment: You have given some sample data, which is good. What the result you are going to expect to get. It would be easier for other to help you if you provide some sample result say: this is the list you would treat them as duplicate and why

Comment: Are you saying that you want to find out if any of the ranges overlap? What exactly do you mean by duplicates?

Comment: sorry, i need to find duplicates in ranges, for instance, first entry range is for example form 100 to 200, second is from 201 to 300 and thirds has values from 299 to 400, I need to find this 299-300 from last entry. and mark it that's all

Comment: At a first sight I don't see duplicated values in your data here above... The first entry you mention 4567890000000000000 has no duplicates...

Comment: mauro, this is samle data. totally i have about 5000 rows only in this table

Comment: Good. So you want to find duplicates in range_begin column... Ok? Are you sure  they didn't ask you to find _overlaps_ considering range_begin-range_end intervals?

Comment: i need to find this overlaps, sorry English is not my native, time to time i 'm not sure how it's call. however, you'r right, this data represent some prepay screech card values, each row represent each distributor ranges, and i need to find overlapping (thank for this) values from range_begin <-> range_end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CREATE TABLE contains a few typos...

I think something like this should work:

```
SQL> select 
         a.*, b.rID as overlapped_id 
     from 
         mdacardrange a inner join mdacardrange b on 
             a.range_begin < b.range_end and 
             a.range_end > b.range_begin and 
             a.rID <> b.rID 
     ;
```

Comment: Good use of cross join. Though MySQL allows the `INNER JOIN` without `ON` clause, other RDMS may not comply. Consider `CROSS JOIN`, or simple list of tables with comma separators for generalized SQL solution for future readers. Also, do note range values are stored as string. Consider a type conversion in sql as the lexicographic equivalent of string may order differently than numeric value especially with digit length differences: 1 > 101 > 2 > 201...